# Unable to connect to server: timeout expired pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, google

I am using Google Cloud computing engine with SSH, which works on Ubuntu.

I have installed Postgres and edited `pg_hba.conf` and  `postgresql.conf`, but after that I am getting this error when I use to create the server of pgAdmin:

```
Unable to connect to server:
timeout expired
```

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) to add Postgres pgAdmin with the computing engine.

I think I have a problem in port.

Comment: Hi Sarthak! Welcome to askubuntu. Please include as much details as possible, so that someone might be able to help you. Try to make your question more clearer.

Comment: Did you check firewall rules allowing postgres 5432 ? Also make sure from your desktop nothing is blocking port to connect GCE Ubuntu host.

Comment: yes I have the check firewall I have both Ingres Engres

Comment: it happens that IPv4 change after some time